# Как сделать TimeLine с подсветкой?

Tags: javascript

Есть таймлайн длинный, и интересует функция которая при скролле вверх или в низ подсвечивала элемент выбранной позиции.
Ближе к наглядности в данном виде, что бы в зависимости от позиции в шапке указывалась категория выделенного элемента.

```css
header {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(102,102,102);
  position: fixed;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  padding: .5em 3.5em .5em 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: .3em;
  -moz-border-radius: .3em;
  border-radius: .3em;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  padding: .1em;
  margin-top: 4em;
  z-index: -1;
}

th {
  padding: .5em;
  background: rgba(206,206,206,0.9);
}

td {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20em 2em;
  background: rgba(206,206,206,0.3);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <select>
    <option>Лето</option>
    <option>Осень</option>
    <option>Зима</option>
    <option>Весна</option>
  </select>
</header>
<table><tr>
    <th>Лето</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Июнь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Июль</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Август</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Осень</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Сентябрь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Октябрь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ноябрь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Зима</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Декабрь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Январь</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Февраль</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Весна</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Март</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Апрель</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Май</td>
  </tr></table>
```

Comment: без javascript на чистом html это не осуществимым мне кажется

Comment: Хорошо, а в каком направлении копать, как это можно правильно назвать?

Comment: ... исправил теги

Comment: но вряд ли вам кто нибудь поможет, здесь работу за автора не делают

Comment: Да мне хотя бы источники знать, как это сделать. мне не нужно что бы давали готовое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

См. событие прокрутки окна - `window.onscroll` и свойство `window.pageYOffset`. Подробнее, например, тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll

Координаты объекта: для DOM-элементов можно узнать их позицию на странице через функцию [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), она возвращает размеры элемента и отступ от краёв viewport'а.

Соответственно, вам надо в обработчике события скроллинга сверять `window.pageYOffset` и отступ каждого из DOM-объектов. Если эти элементы не изменяются на странице, можно их положение выписать заранее в массив, и в событии сверяться с ним, но в этом случае надо список пересчитывать при изменении размеров окна (`window.onresize`).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.